# API design - return which operations the user can perform

Tags: programming-practices, rest, api, api-design, json

My Rest API returns a tree structure like this:

```
  [
   {
    "name":"test old",
    "id": 1,
    "type":"a-object",
    "spend":13,
    "status”: “active”,
    "children":[
        {
          "name":"test women old",
          "id": 2,
          "type":"b-object",
          "spend":13,
          "status”: “active”,
          "children":[..]
         }
     ]
   }
  ]
```

I would like to tell the user for each node which fields could be updated
for example, for the first a-object test old he can only set the status, while for b-object he can set the status, name and spend.

What is the REST API way to do it?

I tried to look for an example for a API that does such a thing and didn't find - do you know of one that does it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To comply with rest you need to manipulate (get,put...) whole resources. Make each modifyable field within your main resource a sub resource... then use hateoas to notify users of the operations that can be performed on each sub resource.